# getting rake test to see tests in a subdirectory..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I wanted to clean up my tests, so I broke a very large one up into multiple files and wanted to store them in a subdirectory inside test/integrations...

However, now rake test does not see them..  How can I tell rake to look in an additional place for test files?

Comment: Is this a Rails app or something else?  If it's a Rails app, `rake test:integration` should already pick up test files in subdirectories.  I've done this on my own Rails apps before and I know it works.  Maybe you can give us more information.

Comment: Yeah I realized that I had accidentally forgotten to append "_test" to the end of the filenames so they weren't being picked up.....  Once I made that adjustment it worked as expected.  Whew!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too, and one thing you can do is place a test within the regular subdirectory (either unit, integeration, functional) and add the lines:

```
system("rake test TEST=test/integration/my_subfolder/test1.rb")
system("rake test TEST=test/integration/my_subfolder/test2.rb")
```

Etc. It's not the nicest solution, but it works. I can't remember now, but I don't think you can use regex in that singular TEST option.